# Attempting to set up Wake on LAN

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan

I've enabled WoL in my BIOS settings and in Windows and I'm trying to use the "WoL Wake On Lan Wan" android app to turn on my computer.

I filled in the following information:
**Name**: (I just picked a name for the connection, I don't think it matters.)
**MAC**: (my MAC address)
**IP or Domain**: (The IP I get when I go to whatismyipaddress.com)
**Port**: (Here it gets difficult, my ISP makes me use their website to configure my router, so everything goes through them first, they only allow me to forward ports between 1023 and 65536 so port 9 can't be opened. I used an arbitrary port and that didn't work.)

I also have a "**Send as Broadcast"** option which lets me fill in a **Subnet**. I just entered 255.255.255.255 here.

I'm not really sure what to do since it doesn't work, I'm using my Antivirus' firewall to check incoming packets and my PC doesn't seem to be receiving them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I had the wrong local IP when I forwarded the ports. After fixing it I could see my antivirus blocking the packets, which meant I was receiving them. I turned my computer off and it worked!